# How can I disconnect this sprayer hose?

Tags: plumbing

[image]

I've already removed the faucet and am trying to disconnect this line so I can remove the weight and pull all the lines through. Does anyone know how I can disassemble this?

Comment: I would look at the bottom of the faucet , with no flats on either side that may be a swivel joint.  If the fitting on the bottom of the faucet is small enough it may slide through the weight as I don’t see a split and that fitting is larger than the metal flex. If the top fitting is smaller that may be the way to go.

Comment: If it's being replace (and doesn't need to be saved), apply a heavy pair of tin snips to the braided line and simply cut it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try vise grip pliers.

If there are no flats spots on the chrome articulated hose's fitting to accept a wrench then i would use a cloth and vise grip pliers to clamp onto the chrome fitting. ( *wrap the cloth around the fitting to protect it from the jaws of the pliers* )

Try to clamp onto the ring of thicker metal closest to the brass fitting  side of the braided hose. Try a **not to tight grip first** and see if it spins. Tighten up the vise grips if the spins.

Once the vise grip pliers are clamped you can use an adjustable wrench on the brass fitting to see if you can loosen the connection.

*If you do not care about the finish of the chrome  then do not use the towel.*

**FYI:** *Vise Grip is a brand name that is commonly use to describe all locking pliers.*